# Evaluation of limit to infinity with nth-root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Hey I am supposed to evaluate the limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}+\left ( \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right )^{n}}, x\geq 0$$

My idea was that I can rewrite it in:
$$e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\left (  \ln\left (  1+x^{n}+\left ( \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right )^{n}\right )\right )} $$

But I do not know, what to do next.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Isn't  also an $n$ in the exponent of $x^2$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, sorry I will edit it

Comment: Wouldn't that be $1$?, Or do you need it with respect to $x$?

Comment: I think this depends on the value of $x$ since this will establish whether $x^n$ will dominate or $(\frac{x^2}{2})^n$ will dominate.

Comment: @user712576 yes, I need it with respect to x

Comment: @KitterCatter can you elaborate it more?

Comment: There are a few cases. $x < 1$: Then $x^n$ and $(x^2/2)^n$  will approach 0 and thus you will probably get a 1. If x>1 but x<2 then the $x^n$ term will be greater than 1, but the $x^2/2$ will be less than 1 and thus approach 0, thus giving x. Finally if $x>2$ then the $x^2/2$ term will dominate and you will get that result

Comment: @KitterCatter thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $a_n$ the sequence and let $x \geq 0$ and $M:=\max\{1,x,\frac{x^2}{2}\}$

$$M \leq a_n \leq\sqrt[n]{3}M$$

So $a_n \to M$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$ then the term $\frac{x^2}{2}$ will only persist as $n\rightarrow \infty$ if the condition $\frac{x^2}{2}> x$ is satisfied and the solution will be $\frac{x^2}{2}$ if on the other hand we have that $\frac{x^2}{2} < x$ then only $x$ will persist and the solution is $x$. If $x\leq 1$ after taking the root the solution will be just $1$.

Comment: I disagree. Take $x=1.5$ and see what happens.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot the 2 which divides $x^2$

Comment: @DinnoKoluh how it will change?

Comment: @PeterF. I forgot the 2 in the denominator because as stated for $x = 1.5$, $\frac{1.5^2}{2}<1.5$ so only $1.5$ remains.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Thanks, now I understand