# Limit to infinity with the nth-root

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

\begin{array}{l}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{array}

Here is my thinking:

\begin{array}{l}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } e^{\log\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\\
\\
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)}{n}\xrightarrow{I'H}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2^{n} \log 2\ +\ 4^{n} \log 4}{1+2^{n} +4^{n}} =\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2^{n} \log 2\ +2\cdot \ 4^{n} \log 2}{1+2^{n} +4^{n}}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
\xrightarrow{I'H}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log 2\left( 2^{n} \log 2+2\cdot 4^{n} \log 4\right)}{2^{n} \log 2+4^{n} \log 4}\\
=\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2^{n} \log 2+2^{2n+2} \log 2}{2^{n} +2^{2n+1}}\\
=\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log 2\left( 1+2^{n+2}\right)}{1+2^{n+1}}\\
=\log 2\\
\\
\therefore \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} =2
\end{array}

And I tried to follow [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405851/evaluation-of-limit-to-infinity-with-nth-root):  \begin{array}{l}1+2^{n} +4^{n} \sim 4^{n} \ \therefore \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{4^{n}} =4\end{array}

I'm confused about which is right. Thanks for your help

Comment: The way you use l'Hospital Rule is not correct :  $(a^x)'\neq x a^{x-1}...$

Comment: @Surb Thanks for your reminder, I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in your final step
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(2)(1+2^{n+2})}{1+2^{n+1}} = 2\ln(2)=\ln(4)
$$
instead of what you said which was $\ln(2)$. You can get this by multiplying the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(2)(1+2^{n+2})}{1+2^{n+1}}\frac{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(2)(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+2)}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+1} = 2\ln(2)
$$
since $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ goes to $0$.

$e^{\ln(4)}=4$ which is your desired answer

Answer (score 1):

In general if we have some positive numbers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k$, then the similar limit still exists and can be found by the same approach:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_k^n)^{1/n}=\max_{m=1,2,\cdots,k}\{a_m\}$$

Answer (score 1):

More simply $$\left( 1+2^{n} +4^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left[4^n\left( \frac1{4^n}+\frac{2^{n}}{4^n} +1\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=(4^n)^\frac1n\left(\frac1{4^n}+\frac{1}{2^n} +1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} =$$

$$=4\left(\frac1{4^n}+\frac{1}{2^n} +1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 4 \cdot 1^0 =4$$

recall indeed that $1^0$ is not an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes LH complicates. Here is simpler solution without LH:

$$
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(4^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \left( \frac{1}{4^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} + 1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
= \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(4^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
\left\{ 1 + \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{4^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) + \cdots \right\}
= 4(1 + 0) = 4
$$

Comment: What is this step $\ldots \left\{ 1 + \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{4^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) + \cdots \right\}$?

Comment: First two terms of the binomial expansion. The remaining terms will have higher powers of $1/n$ then will be infinitely smaller than the second term and so on. So basically we can ignore every term after the first.

Comment: Note that we don't need such kind of step.

Comment: Well there can be more than one way to solve a problem and unless the OP has specifically mentioned that he/she is not interested in other methods, I believe its ok so share an alternate method. Cheers :)

Comment: I agree, but we can simply note that $\left( \frac{1}{4^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} + 1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1^0=1$, we don't need advanced tools.